# Django Rest Framework: How to manipulate value of one field of the model inside view class?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have a model Field and i want to fill in **poi_id** with return value from some external web service:

```
class Field(AbstractModel):
    field_id = models.AutoField("Unique ID for each field", primary_key=True)
    field_exid = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,unique=True)
    field_desc = models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    field_comment = models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    field_country = models.IntegerField()#choices=ALL_COUNTRIES
    field_city = models.IntegerField()#choices=ALL_CITIES
    field_address = models.CharField(max_length=90,blank=True)
    field_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='owner')
    poi_id = models.UUIDField(editable=False)
    last_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='last_user')
```

Besides this user will have to post longitude and latitude which won't be saved inside model but will then be posted to some external web service which returns UUID of created poi.(I want to save this inside as poi_id value)

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class FieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Field
        fields = ['field_exid','field_desc','field_comment','field_country',
'field_city','field_address','poi_id']
```

In View class i have:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])    
def fields_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                poi_id = "00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d0e0f"
                data = request.POST.copy()
                data['poi_id'] = uuid.UUID(poi_id)
                serializer = FieldSerializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When i printed the value of **data** im passing into FieldSerializer im getting:

```
<QueryDict: {u'field_city': [u'1'], u'field_country': [u'941'],
 u'poi_id': [UUID('00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d0e0f')],
 u'longitude': [u'45.879'], u'field_address': [u'cenej 2'], 
 u'field_comment': [u'njiva'], u'field_desc': [u'njiva'],
 u'latitude': [u'19.871'], u'field_exid': [u'njiva']}>
```

But im getting error that poi_id is null nonetheless:

```
 null value in column "poi_id" violates not-null constraint
 DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2015-11-19 09:42:30.145712+00, 
 2015-11-19 09:42:30.145773+00, 12, njiva, njiva, njiva, 941, 1, cenej 
 2, null, null, null).
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove ```editable=False``` for ```poi_id``` field?

Comment: I don't think that is an issue because i printed the value of serializer.data and im getting dictionary without poi_id.                          {'field_city': 1, 'field_country': 931, 'field_address': u'adress', 'field_comment': u'field', 'field_desc': u'field', 'field_exid': u'field1'}
It seems serializer  can't validate uuid:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the serializer could not validate poi_id because i was sending uuid.UUID object and that is not the thing it expects.So i created poi_id uuid field in seializer:

```
poi_id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose')
```

and had to pass poi_id value as string inside view function.